# How to show stock movement from one plant to another, then back?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a large database of stock movements. I want to be able to see if we are sending stock back to the originating plant after it has already shipped the item out.

A miniature version of my data base it below:

| Date | Part No. | Origin | Destination | Cost | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1/29/2023 | 100 | MIA | MCO | $500.00 | 500 |
| 1/29/2023 | 100 | MIA | ATL | $450.00 | 500 |
| 1/30/2023 | 100 | JFK | MIA | $700.00 | 500 |
| 1/30/2023 | 100 | MCO | SFB | $700.00 | 500 |

the expected result would be an output table that summarizes the following:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| # of plants with inbound and outbound | 2 |
| inbound and outbound quantity | 1500 |
| inbound outbound % of volume | 75% |

Comment: Can you explain the logic for deriving the output table?

Comment: # of plants with inbound and outbound -  This is 2 because both MIA and MCO are receiving and sending out stock. Inbound/Outbound Quantity - The sum of the rows containing MIA and MCO. % of total volume - 750/1000, which is the sum of MIA->MCO, JFK->MIA, and MCO->SFB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

Create 3 measures as follows:

```
# of plants with inbound and outbound = 
VAR o = VALUES('Table'[Origin])
VAR d = VALUES('Table'[Destination])
RETURN COUNTROWS(INTERSECT(o, d))


inbound and outbound quantity = 
VAR o = VALUES('Table'[Origin])
VAR d = VALUES('Table'[Destination])
VAR i =  INTERSECT(o, d)
RETURN CALCULATE(SUM( 'Table'[Quantity]), 'Table'[Origin] IN i)

inbound outbound % of volume = 
[inbound and outbound quantity]/SUM('Table'[Quantity])
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this that will allow Drill-through to see the details?

Comment: There are a few ways but they all come with complexity. I'd add another question with very detailed requirements.